# Webdriver xpath multiple matching

Tags: java, xpath, webdriver

For some reason this is not working for me

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//textarea[@id[contains(., 'explanation')]] or input[@id[contains(., 'notes')]]")).sendKeys("auto-generated text");
```

Where can I find syntax rules for joining multiple matching conditions?

EDIT: Just copying explanation to my question >

I want xpath to match one of the elements depending on the page being tested. Two pages have different elements with different id's and tags, so in one case it would match "textarea", in another - "input". I could solve this with one if statement, but I was just curious if xpath could work in this case.

Comment: Don't put it all in your selector.  Just use an if/else.  KISS principle.

Comment: Yeah, I ended up using if/else.

Answer (score 1):

The `or` operator is the Boolean operator which cannot be used here. I assume that you need the union of node sets which is represented by the `|` operator. Be aware that when you make the replacement you have to think about how the nesting levels of both tags `textarea` and `input` relate to each other.

Comment: I want xpath to match one of the elements depending on the page being tested. Two pages have different elements with different id's and tags, so in one case it would match "textarea", in another - "input". I could solve this with one if statement, but I was just curious if xpath could work in this case. Does not look like replacing or with | change anything...

Answer (score 1):

`//*[((name(.)='textarea') and contains(@id,'explanation')) or ((name(.)='input') and contains(@id,'notes'))]` should work, but I can't decide if it's better than an `if` ;-)